# Replace d3.select and onchange function with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to convert this code to jquery. I am quite new to jQuery. in .data(item) the item is a column in the dataset. In the "var item" I get the keys of the column and I pass these keys to the select button.

If I convert this code to jquery then it could be generic to use with another JavaScript library.

Thanks in Advance.

````
                <div id="chart1">
                     <select id="selectButton"></select>
                 </div>

      here in the middle, I have bar chart and update function. And in .on(change function{) i call the update function to redraw the chart based on user selection.

            d3.select("#selectButton")
                .selectAll('myOptions')
                .data(item)
                .enter()
                .append('option')
                .text(function (d)
                {
                    return d; }) // text showed in the menu
                .attr("value", function (d)
                {
                    return d; }) // returned value by the button


            // When the button is changed, run the updateChart function
            d3.select("#selectButton").on("change", function(d) {
                // recover the option that has been chosen
                var selectedOption = d3.select(this).property("value")
                // Run the updatechart function upon selection
                update(selectedOption)})```
````

Comment: As this might change an answer, "it could be generic to use with another JavaScript library" - what gain in portability/cross compatibility are you hoping to gain from using jquery instead of d3?

Comment: Actually I have put this code in Thymeleaf and I have injected the chart from the controller. if I inject d3 code it works fine because here I use d3.select. If I inject High-chart or google-chart then the dropdown could not be updated and the .on(change function will not work since I use d3.select. That's why I prefer to used jquery that works with all javascript-based library.

Comment: I am able to add options to <select id="selectButton"> dynamically with the following code  `
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  var myselect = $('<select>');
                  $.each(used_data, function(index, key) {
                      myselect.append( $('<option></option>').val(key).html(key) );
                  });
                  $('#selectButton').append(myselect.html());

              });` Now i want to change the .on( change function also

Answer (score 0):

I changed it and it works!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              var myselect = $('<select>');
              $.each(used_data, function(index, key) {
                  myselect.append( $('<option></option>').val(key).html(key) );
              });
              $('#selectButton').append(myselect.html());

          });

           $('select').on('change' , function () {

              var selectedOption = $("#selectButton").val();

              update(selectedOption)
           })
```